# How to schedule a jenkins pipeline build for a certain date and time to run once

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to run a bash script in a remote vm (not a jenkins node) and check the status and fetch the stdout to jenkins so I can trigger some other pipelines.

I have tried external-monitor-job plugin but remote vms don't have access to jenkins thus this is not an option.

I want to create a pipeline that runs a bash script in the background and another job to check if this process is finished via it's PID. Bash script will run for quite a while so I cannot keep the jenkins node busy for the whole time so I came up with the following idea.

1. Run the script in the remote vm
2. Check the process. Is it done?

Yes : Fetch the output.logs

No : Schedule job 2 for 10 minutes later

How can I schedule the build to run 10 minutes later ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the internal structure of the execution of a pipeline, you can execute out of a node (i.e. directly on the master). You can then execute your pipeline but put a `sleep` before `pipeline` or `node`. It would give something like that

```
sleep(time:10,unit:'MINUTES')
pipeline{
 agent any
 //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: And with this I wouldn't affect any other pipelines resources by keeping some resources allocated ?

Comment: No because you would allocate resources from the master (which shouldn't be used on a regular basis)